# cuda strange memory access error to shared memory

Tags: cuda

I'm stuck on this for the whole day.
The following program will give "Out of range shared or local address" error.
Commenting out this line will solve this problem.

```
hist[tidx] = 0;
```

However, I don't think allocating shared memory of size 88*4 byte will be any problem.

Commenting out this line will also solve the problem

```
NVMatrix Acts(acts, true);
```

It seems if I allocate the Acts matrix in the global memory, the shared memory will behave abnormal. Any idea?

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    float * act = new float[2985984];
    for (int i=0; i<2985984; i++)
        act[i] = 0.0001*(i+1);

    Matrix acts(act, 23328, 128);   // use act as the data to initialize the 23328x128, matrix in cpu

    NVMatrix Acts(acts, true);      // create a Acts Matrix which uses GPU global memory, and copies the value from CPU to GPU
                                    // If comment out this line, there is no problem to execute the program

    float cost = Calculate();

}

float Calculate()
{
    dim3 blocks(4,96);
    dim3 threads(32,8);

    cudaFuncSetCacheConfig(createShare<8, 32>, cudaFuncCachePreferShared);

    int numLabels = 88;

    createShare<8, 32><<<blocks, threads, numLabels>>>(numLabels);

    return 0;
}

template <int B_Y, int B_X>
__global__ void createShare(int numLabels)
{
    extern __shared__ float hist[];

    int tidx = threadIdx.y * B_X + threadIdx.x;
    if (tidx<numLabels) {
        printf("block %d %d %d\n", blockIdx.x, blockIdx.y, tidx);
        hist[tidx] = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this:

```
createShare<8, 32><<<blocks, threads, numLabels>>>(numLabels);
```

to this:

```
createShare<8, 32><<<blocks, threads, numLabels*sizeof(float)>>>(numLabels);
```

The size of dynamic shared allocation that you are passing to the kernel is in *bytes*.  You need to allocate enough bytes to cover 88 `float` quantities.